# Powershell get-childitem with directory name contains specials caracters

Tags: powershell, utf-8, directory, path, get-childitem

I have a issue with my powershell script to get all files in directory because it's contains an utf8 caracter

when i execute this command directly in powershell window : Test-Path -LiteralPath "G:\Drive partagés", it's ok

but when i do the same command in script.ps1, resultat is false

i don't know how manage utf8 inside my script

thx a lot in advance

i cannot change the name of directory...
and i cannot update regestry...
i tried to force encoding but doesn't work for test-path and get-childitem
i tried to add defautencoding but doesn't work too

Comment: result : G:\Drive partagÃ©s instead of G:\Drive partagés

Comment: powershell 5.1 only understands a script encoded in utf8withbom or unicode (utf16le)

Comment: Which application/editor are you using to write and save your scripts? Notepad? VS Code? Notepad++? PowerShell ISE?

Comment: I use VS Code and tried to NotePad++ but same result

Comment: In VSCode: F1 -> change file encoding -> save with encoding -> UTF8 with BOM. If all else fails, you may use `"G:\Drive partag$([char]233)s"`, but this really shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: simply.... it's work ! thx u're solved my issue

Comment: Since the problem occurs with a _string literal_ in your _source code_, the likeliest explanation is that your script file is misinterpreted by the Windows PowerShell engine, which happens if the script is saved as UTF-8 _without a BOM_. Try saving your script as UTF-8 _with BOM_; see the linked duplicate for details.